# Entity framework update with textbox.text value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need help with updating my entity framework model. I want to find certain field in entity and to update its value with textbox's value.

I tried this:

```
var context1= new Entities1();
using (context1)
{
   var chechUser = (from c in context1.Users
                    where c.Username == LabelUsername.Text
                    select c.Name).Single();

   chechUser = TextBoxNewName.Text;

   context1.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

There is no build errors, but it doesn't work (entity is not updated).

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank in advance.

Comment: My guess is you have to wait for SaveChangesAsync() to complete before going out of scope. Or use SaveChanges().

Comment: since you calling save changes asynchronously, `await context1.SaveChangesAsync();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that EF doesn't know *how* to save this update.

Your "var" is just returning a string, not a database record, so when you alter it's value, it's no longer linked to the db record.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
var context1= new Entities1();
using (context1)
{
   var chechUser = (from c in context1.Users
                    where c.Username == LabelUsername.Text
                    select c).FirstOrDefault();

   if (chechUser == null)
       throw new Exception("Couldn't find a Users record with a Username value of: " + LabelUsername.Text);

   chechUser.Name = TextBoxNewName.Text;

   context1.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

you are changing an entity field not the entity so saving changes do nothing.

```
var chechUser = (from c in context1.Users
                    where c.Username == LabelUsername.Text).Single();
```

now you have the user entity in `chechUser`

```
chechUser.Name = TextBoxNewName.Text;
await context1.SaveChangesAsync();
```

if you are using the `Async` version of `SaveChanges` you should `await` it or call `context1.SaveChanges();` instead.

Comment: (Damn, you beat me to the answer by 1 minute !!)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that. You can't just select one field, update it and send it back to database for save. You have to select one record, change it's property and then save changes back to database.

```
var context1 = new Entities1();
using (context1)
{
    var chechUser = (from c in context1.Users
        where c.Username.ToLower() == LabelUsername.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        select c).Single();

    chechUser.Name = TextBoxNewName.Text;

    await context1.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And as others mentioned, you have to `await` an `async` operation to complete.